# Finding regions of higher numbers in a matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, matrix, gdal

I am working on a project to detect certain objects in an aerial image, and as part of this I am trying to utilize elevation data for the image. I am working with Digital Elevation Models (DEMs), basically a matrix of elevation values. When I am trying to detect trees, for example, I want to search for tree-shaped regions that are higher than their surrounding terrain. Here is an example of a tree in a DEM heatmap:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIvlv.png

I want to be able to find small regions like that that are higher than their surroundings.

I am using OpenCV and GDAL for my actual image processing. Do either of those already contain techniques for what I'm trying to accomplish? If not, can you point me in the right direction? Some ideas I've had are going through each pixel and calculating the rate of change in relation to it's surrounding pixels, which would hopefully mean that pixels with high rates change/steep slopes would signify an edge of a raised area.

Note that the elevations will change from image to image, and this needs to work with any elevation. So the ground might be around 10 meters in one image but 20 meters in another.

Comment: My gut tells me you are looking for haar cascades: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html?highlight=feature

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you can put the DEM information into a 2D Mat where each "pixel" has the elevation value, you can find local maximums by applying **dilate** and then **substract** the result from the original image.

[image]

There's a related post with code examples in: http://answers.opencv.org/question/28035/find-local-maximum-in-1d-2d-mat/